# Getting the indices of the max values of matrix columns in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to get the indices of the maximum values of the columns in a matrix, for example:

```
a =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
```

and I want to get

```
[1, 4, 4, 1]
```

which are the indices of 16,14,15,13 i.e. the maximum value in each column. I discovered that

```
max(a,[],1)
```

returns

```
[16, 14, 15, 13]
```

How can I get their indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find indices, not the numbers themselves, so you need the *second* output argument.

```
[~,I] = max(a)
```

Comment: oh the ~ is a neat trick.  i usually just use a junk variable.

Comment: @thang: Although I think it's not supported in previous versions of MATLAB

Comment: @AlirezaMirian It's been supported for the last four years, so I think it's a pretty safe assumption.